# How do you change the output of count from a tibble to Name Value pairs?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to use the values generated by count() for use in formulas.

```
temp_dhcp %>% 
  group_by(AddressState) %>% 
  count(name = "quantity") -> temp_dhcp_count

temp_dhcp %>% 
  count(AddressState, name = "quantity")
```

Generates a tibble:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  AddressState        quantity
  <chr>                  <int>
1 Active                  6323
2 ActiveReservation       1222
3 Declined                  10
4 Expired                   12
5 InactiveReservation      287
```

I need to take the quantity per line and apply different calculations.
Is there a way to convert each row to the equivalent of

```
Active = 6323
ActiveReservation = 1222
Declined = 10
Expired = 12
InactiveReservation = 287
```

Thank you,

-Jacob

---

Sample output of temp_dhcp as requested by @neilfws

```
> temp_dhcp
# A tibble: 697 x 3
   IPAddress   AddressState        HostName               
   <chr>       <chr>               <chr>                  
 1 10.75.2.69  InactiveReservation REDACTED
 2 10.75.2.72  InactiveReservation REDACTED      
 3 10.75.2.79  InactiveReservation REDACTED
 4 10.75.2.91  InactiveReservation REDACTED
 5 10.75.2.93  InactiveReservation REDACTED               
 6 10.75.2.94  InactiveReservation REDACTED               
 7 10.75.2.95  InactiveReservation REDACTED               
 8 10.75.2.96  InactiveReservation REDACTED              
 9 10.75.2.101 InactiveReservation REDACTED               
10 10.75.2.102 InactiveReservation REDACTED               
# ... with 687 more rows
```

Comment: What are the "different calculations", and why don't you think you can apply them to rows of a tibble?

Comment: I need to estimate dollar costs estimates base don the value:
```
currency(temp_dhcp_count$quantity[1] * 40, digits = 2L, format = "f", big.mark = ",") 
currency(temp_dhcp_count$quantity[2] * 1000, digits = 2L, format = "f", big.mark = ",")
This works, however the dataset does not always return those 5 groups. I would like ```
to extract them so I can:
```
currency(Active * 40, digits = 2L, format = "f", big.mark = ",")
currency(ActiveReservation * 1000, digits = 2L, format = "f", big.mark = ",")
```

Comment: What you’re describing may be easier with something like `ifelse()` or `dplyr::case_when()`. This seems like it may be an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) — you might consider posting a question describing the primary problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: temp_dhcp_count$quantity[1], how do I use the value by name and not $quantity['1']

Different datasets don't always have all 5 states?  If I can query by name that should get me what I need.

Comment: It would help to see some or all of the data in `temp_dhcp`, as plain text.

Comment: As suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71330222/i-need-help-accessing-a-value-in-a-tibble-by-name

Comment: `> temp_dhcp
# A tibble: 697 x 3
   IPAddress   AddressState        HostName               
   <chr>       <chr>               <chr>                  
 1 10.75.2.69  InactiveReservation REDACTED
 2 10.75.2.72  InactiveReservation REDACTED    
 3 10.75.2.79  InactiveReservation REDACTED
 4 10.75.2.91  InactiveReservation REDACTED
 5 10.75.2.93  InactiveReservation REDACTED
 6 10.75.2.94  InactiveReservation REDACTED         
 7 10.75.2.95  InactiveReservation REDACTED          
 8 10.75.2.96  InactiveReservation REDACTED       
...`

Answer (score 0):

`glue::glue_data` can be used for this:

```r
quux %>%
  glue::glue_data("{AddressState} = {quantity}")
# Active = 6323
# ActiveReservation = 1222
# Declined = 10
# Expired = 12
# InactiveReservation = 287
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(AddressState = c("Active", "ActiveReservation", "Declined", "Expired", "InactiveReservation"), quantity = c(6323L, 1222L, 10L, 12L, 287L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your tibble to a named vector like this:

```r
temp_dhcp_count_vec <- temp_dhcp_count$quantity
names(temp_dhcp_count_vec) <- temp_dhcp_count$AddressState

temp_dhcp_count_vec
#>          dataActive   ActiveReservation            Declined             Expired 
#>                6323                1222                  10                  12 
#> InactiveReservation 
#>                 287
```

or like this:

```r
library(magrittr)
temp_dhcp_count_vec <- temp_dhcp_count %$%
  set_names(quantity, AddressState)

temp_dhcp_count_vec
#>          dataActive   ActiveReservation            Declined             Expired 
#>                6323                1222                  10                  12 
#> InactiveReservation 
#>                 287
```

...but, as discussed in the comments to your question, I'm not sure if this is actually the best approach to whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
vals <- with(temp_dhcp_count, setNames(as.list(quantity), AddressState))
```

Gets me exactly what I need.

Thanks [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick)

A little more digging and

```
deframe() %>% 
  as.list()
```

works as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).